# Body does not extend to very end of the page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have a footer in my website, and I have some text in this footer which I would like to align at the bottom right of the page.

The footer looks like this:

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row copyright-container col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="copyright">
          <p>&copy; Some Copyright Stuff 2011 - 2020</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My SCSS looks like this

```
.copyright {
      bottom: 0;
      right:0;
    }
```

I just want to align the thing at the very bottom right. It kind of does that, but my body does not seem to extend to the very end of the page, but I dont know why.

I have tried to give my body a height of 100%, but this also didnt help (`<body style="height:100%;">`). I tried the same for my html.

My snippet looks like this. As you can see everything works, but on my computer the body is just ending at 2/3 of the page. Why could this be?

```css
.copyright {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      right:0;
 }
 
 .bg {
 background-color: black;
 }
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row copyright-container col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
      <div class="copyright">
        <p> Some Copyright 2011 - 2020</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I just tried that, and it seems to work on here. The problem seems to be that my body does not extend over the full page, so its height stops at some point, and this is also why my text does not move fully down. What could I do? I am also not sure how to replicate this here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using col-md-* then you should add col-sm-* and col-xs-*, so if your screen is small, the suitable css will get applied. This might one of the reason your code doesn't work.

```
 <div class="copyright col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-10 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-10 col-md-2 col-md-offset-10">
      <p>Some Copyright Stuff 2011 - 2020</p>
    </div>
```

Or you can do that with pure css as I added the code below, but use css not scss, as browser doesn't understand scss([Nested code in scss/sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44292471/nested-code-in-scss-sass/44292946#44292946)).

```css
.copyright {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      right:0;
 }
```

```html
<div class="copyright">
   <p>Some Copyright Stuff 2011 - 2020</p>
</div>
```